# MySQL LIKE clause with comma

Tags: mysql

What is the meaning of comma in the following SQL statement (using MySQL)?

[...] `LIKE '%,cat233,%'`

Comment: You need to accept previous answers before asking new. You have already asked 7n questions and newer accepts answers.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't the commas just part of the string to be matched? e.g. "fred,bill,cat233,joe,harry" would match.

Answer (score 2):

checking for `cat233` which is in [comma separated values.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: You are right, although using CSV inside a database cell is horrible design, plus it's slow (string searching). For some reason, people insist on implementing it instead of a 1-to-n table.

Answer (score 1):

It has no special meaning. It just look for string `,cat233,` with 0 or more character in front and 0 or more character after it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it would just match the comma as well; so:

Matches:

```
"My text,cat233,some other stuff"
"My text ,cat233, some other stuff"
"My text,cat233,"
",cat233,"
```

Doesn't match:

```
"My text cat233 some other stuff"
"My text cat233, some other stuff"
"My text, cat233, some other stuff"
```